# DotNetNuke 7.xx (DNN) CMS & How To - Document Management module

Tags: content-management-system, dotnetnuke

I am old DNN user, used versions 1.0 - 4.0 years ago. Now I'm coming back to version 7.xx, While I can see huge improvements they come with increased complexity and I have struggled to find definitive answer to the following question:

**What is the best way to setup a documents management repository with private (current user only) & members only areas without using third party modules?**

Versioning is not essential, but nice to have. The core requirement is the private & members only read only document access.

P.S. *Might consider paid modules, but only if developed for DNN 7 from day one and with good support*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this not helps you, because I think you needs a specific module for the users can manage his own folder, but DNN7 creates a private folder for each user in /Portals/XX/Users/[UserId].

If this not convince you, you can go to Admin>FileManagement and create a folder with specific permisions. To do that:

1. Create New Folder
2. Right Click over the folder you just create and edit the permissions for that folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll give it a try... Is there any module that shows the content of this "default" user folder to the current user?

Comment: Yes, Default HTML Module. If you go to add an image/document you should see a folder named my folder (I think)...